# Explain how this stochastik function works

Tags: algorithm, clojure, stochastic

In the book "Clojure for Finance" I found a function like that:

```
(defn stochastic-k [last-price low-price high-price]
  (let [hlrange (- high-price low-price)
        hlmidpoint (/ hlrange 2)
        numerator (if (> last-price hlmidpoint)
                    (- last-price hlmidpoint)
                    (- hlmidpoint low-price))]
     (/ numerator hlrange)))
```

The author describes it as:

> stochastic-k: This gives us our percentage of price movement of the high/low price.

*(Quote and code from "[Clojure for Finance](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/clojure-finance)", by Timothy Washington)*

I tried the function in the REPL, but it's output doesn't make sense to me:

```
user=> (println (stochastic-k 18 13 23))
13/10
```

So the result is `1.3`, but I would actually expect `1.0`, because 18 is the midpoint of the range from 13 to 23, as far as I can tell.

Can anyone explain to me how the function is supposed to work?

Comment: I think it is either a typo or a bug. The calculation doesn't match the definition of `stochastic-k`

Comment: @AlanThompson I think so too, when talking about `stochastik-k`, I think the author wanted to implement this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_oscillator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the implementation in my opinion. I think the numerator should be like:

```
numerator (if (> last-price hlmidpoint)
                    (- last-price hlmidpoint)
                    (- hlmidpoint last-price))
```

And then the function would produce a fraction representing how much does the `last-price` differ from the average price in the range.

Comment: Is there any documentation of the functon that the author tried to implement? I still don't understand quite how to interpret the outout.

Comment: @Max I believe it is this one: http://www.tradingsolutions.com/functions/StochasticOscillator.html However I am not an expert and although it seems very simple intuitively, I find the terminology somewhat confusing

Comment: Thank you, I was already thinking that the implementation is wrong, as the output doesn't make sense. Unfortunately this is not the only mistake in the books code examples, there are some very obvious syntax errors.